# How to speed up object detection while using faster rcnn/ ssd models

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, video-processing, object-detection

I've got 50 videos spanning 90 minutes each. Now I'm running SSD for object detection and saving the frames with objects and their timestamps in a csv file.
But the problem is that it still takes entire 90 minutes for each of the videos. My question :- Is there any way by which I can somehow kind of fast forward the SSD object detection model so that each video gets done in let's say 10/20 minutes maybe ?

Comment: you can use **Yolo** if you are looking for real-time detection. In the meanwhile, maybe you can perform detection at each say 10 frames and use some tracking algorithm (e.g. BACF) for the rest of the frames.

Comment: How to perform detection at only 10fps ?

Comment: When you take the frames from the video to feed them to SSD, you can just take one frame out of 10 (feed each 10th frame to SSD) and use tracking for the 9 frames in between.

Comment: Judging from your statement, could it be something wrong with how you process the video? Like you are playing the video at 30 FPS no matter what and only process the frame when it is played.

Answer (score 0):

Is every single frame really matter to you? If not, just run the detection every x frames only, not on every frame. for example use:

```
if (frame%2 == 0)
{
run detection
}
```

for taking only every two frames (even number frame)

Comment: But still that would take entire video length time